# Cron Job (PHP) --> selecting records from next year not working

Tags: php, mysql, cron

```
ID  | Client  |    Data    | Hosting   | Price |
    |         |            |           |       |
    |         | 2018-01-02 | Heineken  | 500   |
    |         | 2018-01-03 | Hestia    | 200   |
    |         | 2017-12-28 | Bravo     | 200   |
    |         | 0000-00-00 |           |       |
    |         | 0000-00-00 |           |       |
```

Why when I want the PHP code to select the records from next year with date **2018-01-03** which is 7 days from right now **(2017-12-27)** my code does not return any matching records (even though there are records with this date)? This is my crone code:

```
<?php

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
    include_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'stdeja_przypomnien', 'admin123', 'stdeja_root');

    $tbl_2 = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE date(data_waznosci) = CURDATE()+7;");

    if($tbl_2->num_rows == 1) {
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        foreach($tbl_2 as $email => $details) {        
            $fullname = $details['klient'] . ' ' . $details['data_waznosci'];

            $mail->addAddress('piterdeja@gmail.com');
            $mail->setFrom('system_przypomnien_hosting@powiadomienia.pl');
            $mail->Subject = "Hosting - system przypomnień";
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Body = "W dniu {$details['data_waznosci']} kończy się hosting klientowi {$details['klient']} na KWOTĘ {$details['cena']}, hosting to {$details['Hosting']}";

            if ($mail->send())
                echo "Formularz został wysłany. Postaramy się odpowiedzieć jak najszybciej.";
            else
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }             


}  
?>
```

Surprisingly so, when I select tomorrow date 2017-12-28 with the code: CURDATE()+1 selection **DOES work** (returns matching record 'Bravo');

Answer (score 0):

Try using date_add()

```
$tbl_2 = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM subjects 
      WHERE date(data_waznosci) = date_add(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);");
```

Comment: WORKS thank you ! :) I wonder why CURDATE()+7 selection was not working..

Comment: You don't have to use DATE_ADD function. MySQL can add just fine with `CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY` @Hieronimes